# I'm searching for $X$ and $V$ such that the evaluation map $f:H^n(X,A;V)\to \hom_\mathbb{Z}(H_n(X,A;\mathbb{Z}),V)$ is not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $(X,A)$ a pair of topological spaces. We define the pairing-map in singular co- homology$$H^n(X,A;V)\times H_n(X,A;\mathbb{Z})\to V$$ $$([\xi ],[\alpha])\mapsto \xi (\alpha).$$This map induces a map $$f:H^n(X,A;V)\to \hom_\mathbb{Z}(H_n(X,A;\mathbb{Z}),V)$$ $$ [\xi ]\mapsto ([\alpha ]\mapsto \xi (\alpha)).$$We proved that this map is always surjective, but not injective in general.

I want to discuss an example where $f$ is not injective. First of all, we later discussed the universal coefficient theorem in cohomology which states:

Let $R$ be a principal integral domain, $W$ a $R$-module and $X$ be a topolocial space. Then there is a short exact sequence

$$0\to Ext_R^1(H_{n-1}(X;R),W)\to H^n(X;W)\to \hom_R(H_n(X;R),W)\to 0$$and I  noticed that $f$ with $A=\emptyset$ is a special case of the map $H^n(X;W)\to \hom_R(H_n(X;R),W)$ in the short exact sequence with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $W= \mathbb{Z}$-module. Therefore I'm searching for a topolical space $X$, a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $W$ such that $Ext_R^1(H_{n-1}(X;R),W)$ is nonzero.

My suggestion: $X=S^1$ the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}$, $n=1$ and $W=\mathbb{R}$ considered as a $\mathbb{Z}-$ module, but it seems that something is wrong: We have $H^1(S^1;\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$, $\hom_\mathbb{Z}(H_1(S^1;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{R}))\cong \mathbb{R}$ (what I want to avoid..) and $Ext_\mathbb{Z}^1(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$. What is wrong here?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R})=0$, not $\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z},W)=0$ for any $W$, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  In fact, $\mathbb{R}$ is also an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module (though this is harder to prove), so $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{R})=0$ for any $A$.

This means that you'll need an example where $H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$ and $W$ is not $\mathbb{R}$.  Actually I would start by just looking for some pair of groups $(A,W)$ such that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(A,W)$ is nontrivial.  Then you just have to find a space $X$ such that $H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong A$.

Here's one such example:

> Take $A=W=\mathbb{Z}/2$, $n=2$, and $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: ok thank you! This example with the real projective space was my second idea which I had in mind, because $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.